# Get column indices for non-zero values in each row in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the following foreach row, the column indices where the column value > 0. If possible a vectorized approach. An example data frame

```
c1  c2  c3  c4 c5 c6 c7 c8  c9
 1   1   0   0  0  0  0  0   0
 1   0   0   0  0  0  0  0   0
 0   1   0   0  0  0  0  0   0
 1   5   5   0  0  1  0  4   6
```

The output is expected to be

```
[0, 1]
[0]
[1]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One quick option is to apply [`numpy.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to each row:

```
import numpy as np

df.apply(np.flatnonzero, axis=1)

0                [0, 1]
1                   [0]
2                   [1]
3    [0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

If you care about performance, here is a pure numpy option (caveat for this option is if the row doesn't have any non zero values, it will be ignored in the result. Choose the method that works for you depending on your need):

```
idx, idy = np.where(df != 0)
np.split(idy, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(idx) != 0) + 1)

[array([0, 1], dtype=int32), 
 array([0], dtype=int32), 
 array([1], dtype=int32), 
 array([0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: very nice, I feel bad I didn't think of it :p +1

Answer (score 1):

Not as sexy as @Psidom's answer, but still, here is a solution using [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.argwhere(df.gt(0).values)).groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
```

output:

```
0                [0, 1]
1                   [0]
2                   [1]
3    [0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
```

Just for fun, here is a pandas version:

```
s = df.set_axis(range(len(df.columns)), axis=1).stack()
s[s.gt(0)].reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```